# Ways of PCB Etching other than Photosensitive Spray or Toner Transfer

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

Toner Transfer is not an option for large quantity or quick production and in my area I could not find any photosensitive sprays.

I tried with screen printing emulsion, but it does not stick with the copper quite well after exposure. I tried also with plastic paint by screen printing process, but I couldn't achieve the resolution I wanted (12 mil trace with 12 mil clearance).

The plastic paints sticks with the copper quite well but it is not VU Curable. Does mixing the plastic paint with the emulsion will make any use to me?

If it still don't work I got a last option of [this](http://www.indiamart.com/indugroup/lpi-photo-imageable-plating-resist-etching-inks.html).
But it is not available in low quantities. They provide a minimum of 20kg. But for my need 1kg will be enough.

What should I do?

Comment: CNC milling is an option you haven't considered. However, I used to make all my own PCBs. I don't bother now, with services like iTead, OSHPark, etc, being so cheap.

Comment: I want something local, I don't like it when the shipping cost and custom charges exceeds the actual cost of the product, or may sometimes become the double of that.
CNC Milling only replaces the etching and drilling part, with very costly machine, not suitable for my use.

Comment: You mean there are **NO** PCB manufacturers in India??? That's hard to believe.

Comment: No! I didn't said that. There is no online one with such easily usable interface (I mean like it is not as easy as just submitting the layout and getting it in front of your door), I know some manufacturers locally, but I want to do it myself. As I know they do it by screen printing, maybe with a less resolution. I think its time to decrease my resolution any try another time.

Comment: @Jem: I seriously doubt these local manufacturers you mention produce PCBs by screen printing.  They almost certainly use some kind of photographic process.

Comment: Doing it yourself is not a wise choice for quantity.  It takes investment in tools, technique, and material handling to make boards efficiently, and unless you want to get out of the design business and into the board making business instead, your time is better served developing a relationship with someone in that business who can get you 10 pieces by Friday.  When **you only need one, and you need it this afternoon**, then it is *sometimes* appropriate to get out your printer and your iron and your etchant.

Comment: One possibility is pre-sensitized PCBs such as here: http://www.circuitspecialists.com/printed-circuit-board-supplies-positive-photo-resist-pre-sensitized-pcbs

Comment: Doing it yourself is only viable as a hobby venture, it would not production qualified in quality *or* cost unless your express goal is starting a PCB fab. There is no way the cost of shipping a stack of boards from China is more expensive. In any case, many board fabs out there don't have a web presence, most do not have any online drawing submission process. If you need to do quantity then you need to walk/drive/fly around and knock on doors, don't expect a one-stop solution

Answer (score 1):

I saw a video once where a guy used finger nail polish & finger nail polish remover (acetone). This question is a bit old by now, but that technique is inexpensive & may work for some people--but, perhaps not for 12 mils precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you must roll your own, try dry resist film; there'a a zillion videos on YouTube about how to do it.

Comment: I know about dry resist film, but it is still a costly and time consuming process and moreover that it is not available in India.